# using grunt-browserify in Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

I'm having some trouble finding an explanation for how to use grunt-browserify.  Looking in their examples folder, I'm looking under the browserify node under their basic example and I see the following:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
      vendor: {
        src: [],
        dest: 'public/vendor.js',
        options: {
          require: ['jquery'],
          alias: [
            './lib/moments.js:momentWrapper', //can alias file names
            'events:evt' //can alias modules
          ]
        }
      },
      client: {
        src: ['client/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'public/app.js',
        options: {
          external: ['jquery', 'momentWrapper'],
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
      'public/main.js': ['public/vendor.js', 'public/app.js']
    }
  });
  grunt.loadTasks('../../tasks');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify', 'concat']);
};
```

What are "vendor" and "client" and where are they documented?  In the README file, they mention "preBundleCB", "dist" and I've seen quite a few others, and most have their own data structures.  Are these options enumerated and explained anywhere?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the convention of Grunt configuration](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks), "vendor" and "client" are `targets`. Their names are not defined by grunt or grunt-browserify. You can create as many targets as you want and give them the names you like. Each target has `files` configuration, which is common in most of Grunt tasks, such as `src` and `dest`, and `options` configuration, which is plugin specific. "dist" is another example of targets and "preBundleCB" is a property of `grunt-browserify`'s options.

You can individually invoke the targets with `grunt browserify:vendor` and `grunt browserify:client`. And `grunt browserify` invokes all targets of `browserify` task, which are "vendor" and "client" in this example.

Each target of grunt-browserify creates a bundled script file. In this example, "vendor" target creates `vendor.js` that contains `jquery`, `moment.js` named `momentWrapper` and `events` named `evt`. "client" target creates `app.js` that contains `client/**/*.js` and their dependencies excluding `jquery` and `momentWrapper`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  One thing I wanted to add to this log, the file executing against the browserify node in grunt.initConfig can be found in node_modules.grunt-browserify.tasks.browserify.  New to grunt and I did not understand the relationship.